# Is there a way to push email settings to all the computers on the network as per User profile?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2016, exchange-2013

We have Exchange 2013 and use Office 2016 and I was wondering if there's a way that I can make a GPO to push the email settings to a user profile right after they login to their profile for the first time.
I tried looking it up online but I was not able to find any step by step guide that can result any success.
Can anyone give me any kind go advice on how to make this possible?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There are group policy administrative templates for Office 2016.  Have you looked at those?

Comment: I have and It shows me a lot of different templates and one in particular stood out. "Automatically configure profile based on Active Directory Primary SMTP adress". Will enabling this do the trick?

Comment: IT WORKED. I enabled that particular Policy, applied it to a certain OU and checked and it works. Thank you @Ramhound for the suggestion.